# Service is not started from alarm receiver

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I'm new to android .my objective is to start a service at a specefic time .the code above is not showing good results.

Alarm receiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiverActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent background = new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class);
    context.startService(background);
}}
```

Service class:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public class BackgroundService extends Service {
private boolean isRunning  = false;
private Context context;
private Thread backgroundThread;






@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}



private Runnable myTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        //task

        stopSelf();
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    this.context = this;
    this.isRunning = true;
    this.backgroundThread= new Thread(myTask);
    }






@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    this.isRunning = false;
    stored3();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //if(!this.isRunning) {
        //this.isRunning = true;
        this.backgroundThread= new Thread(myTask);
        this.backgroundThread.start();
        stored4();
    //}

    return START_STICKY;
}}
```

the Oncreate method is not executed by system so i guess the problem comes from the alarm receiver .Is there any trouble with code ?. i'll be grateful for any help.

Comment: How are you determining that the `Service` isn't starting? Do you have a `<service>` element in your manifest for `BackgroundService`? Are you sure the `BroadcastReceiver` is running?

Comment: service is declared in manifest file. by a check with   "dumpsys alarm"   alarms are triggered in time ,if this was ok so why the broadcast receiver would not start the service ?

Comment: How are you determining that the `BroadcastReceiver` and `Service` aren't running? Have you put log prints, or breakpoints, in the `BroadcastReceiver` and `Service`?

Comment: using a shared preferences record and logs nothing of those things worked .the problem is apparently issued from system alarms of avd. i'm working on disabling  it.